# Заполнение imput поля JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, авторизация, формы

На сайте есть форма ввода input.
Я пытался заполнить её скриптом ниже:

```
jQuery("#codenumber").trigger("click");
document.getElementById('codenumber').value = "5701";
jQuery("#codenumber").trigger("click");
```

Поле заполняется, но сайт возвращает "Неверный код подтверждения", скорее всего, заполнение происходит с отслеживанием нажатия клавиш.
Поэтому, если вводить SMS код вручную, то проверка проходит и  отправляется корректно.

В связи с этим мне необходимо имитировать нажатие клавиш при вводе кода в поле imput.
Как имитировать ввод в поле с помощью js,jq ввод конкретного числа н.п 4154 с имитацией, что как будто это я лично ввел с клавиатуры?

Comment: Ничего непонятно.

Comment: Все еще непонятно. Попробуйте перечитать Ваш вопрос, как-будто Вы ничего про него не знаете. Тогда Вы поймете, как нам трудно приходится.

Comment: Зачем нужна Ваша первая строчка `jQuery("#codenumber").trigger("click");`?

Comment: @Igor До этого там был необходимо было ввести номер телефона и для ввода там надо было нажать на поле, иначе введенный текст не записывался.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#codenumber")[0].focus(); // - ??
document.getElementById('codenumber').value = "5701";
jQuery("#codenumber").trigger("click");
```

Comment: заполнение по вашему коду происходит точно так же как и по моему.
Пример сайта https://my.5ka.ru/registration Там вводишь телефон, потом нужно ввести номер из смс, но он не вводиться этим способом